# Add and remove clicked html elements from array in vue

Tags: arrays, vue.js

Here’s my code

```
<form>
    <div v-for="(inputAvion, index) in inputsAvion" :key="inputAvion.id" :id="`avion-${index}`">
      <input placeholder="origin" name="data" />
      <input placeholder="destination" />
      <div class="ui button small green" @click="addAvion">+</div>
      <div
        class="ui button small red"
        @click="removeAvion(inputAvion)"
        v-show="inputsAvion.length > 1"
      >
        -
      </div>
      {{ index }}
    </div>
  </form>
```

And the script part :

```
<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.inputsAvion.push(this.inputsAvion.length + 1);
    //this.inputsAvion.push(this.inputsAvion);
  },
  data() {
    return {
      inputsAvion: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addAvion() {
      this.inputsAvion.push(this.inputsAvion.length + 1);
    },
    removeAvion(index) {      
     this.inputsAvion.splice(index, 1);
     console.log(this.inputsAvion)
     console.log(index)
    }
  },
};
```

I would like to add the div element each time the button “+” is clicked and assign a unique id to the div (I willl then add autocomplete google map places to calculate distance between 2 locations)
I think I did it correctly … hope so ^^

But I’d like to use also a remove button to delete the selected line. I’ve tried a lot of things but only managed to remove the last “div” added not the one I clicked.

If someone could help me I’d be grateful a lot ! :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the index instead of `inputAvion`

```
 @click="removeAvion(index)"
```

then

```
removeAvion(index) {      
 this.inputsAvion.splice(index, 1);
 ...
```